# Claims of subjectivity are themselves often subjective

Tags: discussion, migration, subjective

I asked a [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/86330/25589) that I believe can be useful to C++ programmers getting used to the new C++0x standard. Someone moved it to SE.Programmers (a site I also am a big fan off). However, I feel that this move is completely incorrect.

How can I defend against claims of subjectivity which, I believe, are at the source of this move? I tried defending through comments but clearly it didn't work, nor were my comments responded to reasonably by whoever migrated the question.

I care very much about the SO and SE communities, and feel that moving this question makes it less useful since it **is** programming-related not programmer-related.

Edit: The question was [migrated back to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6434971/627517). Thanks for everyone's help and patience.

Comment: Subjectivity is subjective? YOU DON'T SAY!

Comment: Well that's just like, your opinion, man

Comment: Wow, it's already gone from Programmers.

Comment: @Shog9, "claims of subjectivity" are not necessarily by definition subjective, but often are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can always oppose a migration (or defend any sort of action, for that matter) by posting on the appropriate Meta site. Explain why you think that it *does* belong on the site it originated, and why it should not have gone to Programmers. If your argument makes people realize they were in error, then the migration can be undone via mod intervention. The overall goal of things is proper order - **fixing incorrect closures and migrations is just as important to the system as closing inappropriate content is**.

If people cannot be convinced, please be open to the thought that maybe the migration *was* appropriate, rather than simply end up frustrated that people do not listen. I'm not suggesting to abandon hope (many a closure and migration has been identified as erroneous), simply keep an open mind as you go about your defense as the discussion progresses - listen to the defenses provided by your opponents. Much like the migrators should be open to being convinced by your argument, you should be open to being convinced by theirs.

Comment: Thanks Grace. Will do. This was my first migration. First love hurts the most ;-)

Answer (score 5):

One way would be to post to meta either here or on [Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com). You can also flag the question for moderator review.

As it happens, your question was brought up on [Programmers chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1200961#1200961) today as a potentially wrong migration.

I myself think it's a bit of a grey area question as it could fit on either site, but we can ask a Stack Overflow moderator to undo the migration.

**Edit:** The migration has been undone.

Comment: The deed has been undone.

Comment: Hurrah! The system that fixes the other system works!